# Symfony 6 - How can I change file upload to multiple file uploads

Tags: symfony, validation

I'm working on a project where a user is able to upload a file. My code works when a single file is uploaded, but I need to change it so a user is able to upload multiple files.

I want to store the files in my database as String. Currently it is stored as example: "file1.png". When uploading multiple files I would like it to be stored as "file1.png;file2.png;file3.png".
However when I add the "multiple => true" in the form, I get an error when pressing submit by the validator that the input needs to be a String.

My best guess is that I need to use Data transformers, but after reading the docs I still don't know how to approach this. ?

[Data Transform](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html)

This is the controller (currently it expects a single file, as for multiple I would use foreach):

```
\#\[Route('/new', name: 'app_blog_new', methods: \['GET', 'POST'\])\]
\#\[IsGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED')\]
public function new(Request $request, BlogRepository $blogRepository, SluggerInterface $slugger, MailerInterface $mailer): Response
{
$blog = new Blog();
$form = $this-\>createForm(BlogType::class, $blog);
$form-\>handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $additionalImages = $form->get('additional_images')->getData();
        if ($additionalImages) {
            $originalFilename = pathinfo($additionalImages->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $safeFilename = $slugger->slug($originalFilename);
            $newFilename = $safeFilename . '-' . uniqid() . '.' . $additionalImages->guessExtension();
    
            try {
                $additionalImages->move(
                    $this->getParameter('blogimage_directory'),
                    $newFilename
                );
            } catch (FileException $e) {
                // ... handle exception if something happens during file upload
            }
    
            $blog->setAdditionalImages($newFilename);
        }
}
```

If I add "multiple => true' to this form I get an "expected String" error on the front.
This is the form used to upload images to a blog:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('additional_images', FileType::class, [
            'label' => 'Additional images',
            'mapped' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'constraints' => [`your text`
                new File([
                    'maxSize' => '1024k',
                    'mimeTypes' => [
                        'image/*',
                    ],
                    'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload a valid image',
                ])
            ],
        ]);
        $builder->get('additional_images')
            ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
                function ($additionalAsArray) {
                    // transform the array to a string
                    return implode('; ', $additionalAsArray);
                },
                function ($additionalAsString) {
                    // transform the string back to an array
                    return explode('; ', $additionalAsString);
                }
            ))
        ;
}
```

This is the blog entity class which contains the image(s)

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: BlogRepository::class)]
class Blog
{
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $additional_images = null;
}
```

I tried adding 'multiple => true' to the form and it works, as the user is able to select multiple files. But after submitting I get "implode(): Argument #1 ($pieces) must be of type array, string given"

Answer (score 2):

I found out that all I had to do was add "new All" to the form:

```
    ->add('additional_images', FileType::class, [
        'label' => 'Additional images',
        'mapped' => false,
        'required' => false,
        'multiple' => true,
        'constraints' => [
            new All([
                new File([
                    'maxSize' => '1024k',
                    'mimeTypes' => [
                        'image/*',
                    ],
                    'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload a valid image',
                ])
            ])
        ],
    ]);
```

And made my controller work with an array:

```
    $additionalImages = $form->get('additional_images')->getData();
    if ($additionalImages) {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($additionalImages as $image)
        {
            $originalFilename = pathinfo($image->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $safeFilename = $slugger->slug($originalFilename);
            $newFilename = $safeFilename . '-' . uniqid() . '.' . $image->guessExtension();

            try {
                $image->move(
                    $this->getParameter('blogimage_directory'),
                    $newFilename
                );
            } catch (FileException $e) {
                // ... handle exception if something happens during file upload
            }
            $result[] = $newFilename;
        }
        $blog->setAdditionalImages(implode(";", $result));
```

}